# Capture "auto-suggest" event using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, autosuggest

I have created a nice cross-browser utility which ensures that form "placeholders" behave in the same way (including IE which does not implement them)

However, this has created a different problem when a user fills a form and the browser helpfully provides an auto-suggest for the remaining fields in the form, eg, for a registration form: You might type your name, and the browser will auto-suggest your surname, email address, postal address, etc...

I don't care what the auto-suggested values are, but I need find a way of capturing "event" on each field so I may hide my implementation of the place holder.

I've had a look at the DOM elements in Chrome to see if the auto-suggest value is stored in a custom attribute, but have been unsuccessful.

Has anyone else seen or experienced this? Does anyone know if its even possible to capture such an event?

**NOTE: This issue disappears when the user accepts the auto-suggest, and this becomes an auto-complete, which fires a change event on the fields; so I only need to capture the suggest event**

Answer (score 0):

I have produced the following script which "detects" when the fields have become auto-suggested by Webkit:

I am assuming anyone using this knows Underscore and jQuery.

```
var $form = $('form'),
    autoCompleteSetting = $form.attr('autocomplete');

if (_.isUndefined(autoCompleteSetting) || autoCompleteSetting === "on") {
    _($form.find('input')).each(function($input){
        setInterval(function() {
            if ($input.is(":-webkit-autofill")) {
                // do your code here to detect the webkit autofill setting
            }
        }, 100);
    });  
}
```

I personally have put the webkit-autofill check into a ternary operator.

Obviously use at your own risk; having these intervals running for every field on your page every millisecond may cause problems for some users!